# How can I run applet code after calling MainFrame?

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe

How can I run some code after calling MainFrame with Java Applets? Is this possible?

```
Frame frame = new MainFrame(new ClassName(),256,256);
System.out.println("This won't print!");
```

Can someone explain how I can get that to print after calling MainFrame?

Comment: How do you run your program? If you are using the console, it should print. Similarly with NetBeans: it prints to the Output windoe. I don't know about Eclipse.

Comment: Create a new thread for your frame.

Comment: After taking a second look at your code, I suggest that you use a debugger to trace into the `MainFrame` and `ClassName` constructors. You probably should modify your code to store a `ClassName` reference so you can separate out the constructor calls for debugging.

Comment: Also, your title doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question. Where's the applet code you are trying to run?

Comment: I don't get an error, my ClassName constructor runs, and everything in it, but the print line won't run.

Comment: The code I'm trying to run is well over 100 lines and I didn't want to make everyone's scroll bar smaller then an ant xD

Comment: @1Topcop How do you know that the ClassName constructor runs? Also, are you sure that it completes and allows the MainFrame class to run?

Comment: As for the 100 lines of code, you are right to not want to post all of it. Take a look at [this page](http://www.sscce.org) for some suggestions about posting the smallest amount of code that you can come up with to illustrate what you want to do and the problems you have encountered trying to do it. (The code I posted in my answer is an example of an SSCCE, but it doesn't recreate the trouble you are having.)

Comment: Alright, where should I post a shortened version of my code?

Comment: To follow the advice of @Code-Guru - post an SSCCE directly into the question (edit the question).  And  use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML. To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: BTW what does *"..with Java Applets"* mean?  What does this have to do with applets?

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have a `MainFrame` class in it's standard libraries.

What you are probably seeing is a program that can run as both an Applet and an application.
When running as an application, the main GUI class is apparently called `MainFrame`, and the line you quote is where it is constructed. Note that it receives an instance of class `ClassName`; that's probably where the logic of the program resides (the model).

Your `System.out.println` *will* be called after the `MainFrame(...)` constructor is done.
Only if the system is exited (by a call to `System.exit(int)` for example) before it can return from the constructor call, will your `System.out.println` not be reached.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but what int would I put so that MainFrame will finish without terminating?

Comment: `System.exit(int)` will always terminate the program. The int is merely a status code for the process that started the program.

Comment: @1Topcop The answer is not telling you to use System.exit.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple example, take a look at this code:

```
package mainframe;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author codeguru <codeguru@users.sourceforge.net>
 */
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new MainFrame();

        System.out.println("This prints.");
    }
}
```

This gives the expected output:

```
This prints.
```

From your original code, I don't see where the applet is that you refer to in your question's title. In order to help you, we need to know more about `MainClass` and `ClassName`. These look like custom classes which you wrote or are part of the example you are studying.